# How to track what process is locking unix account

Tags: linux

I have a problem on one of our servers where our main application user is being locked out on a daily basis due to invalid login attempts. I suspect that there is some batch script running on the box which is using the wrong password for that username

Besides faillog -u *username* which only tells me about the latest failed login it doesn't provide much such as the process which was attempting to log on etc etc.

Does anyone have any tips on what I can use or how I can set up something to give me more information on the process that is causing the account to be locked out?

Comment: Check the syslog of type security. It might help. But dont be suprised when it is sshd :)

Comment: is the user name something easy to guess? if so then it's quite possibly a dictionary attack over ssh.

Comment: no it is not something easy to guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what

```
sudo cat /var/log/auth/log | grep sshd | grep [username]
```

spits out. If you you have ssh open to the outside world, then most probably someone is trying dictionary attacks on that user.

Comment: /var/log/auth does not exist on my machine

Comment: @Richie can you pls check in `/var/log/secure`? Some Linux versions replaced `auth` with `secure`. Generally, you can check `/etc/syslog.conf` for `auth` log location via `vi` or `grep "authpriv.\*" /etc/syslog.conf` hope this helps.

Comment: @Richie seems `grep sshd` and `grep [username]` output overlap on my sys log file. I was able to further narrow down the output by using `cat /var/log/secure | grep "pass.*[user name]"`.